# Celery discovers all tasks even when `app.autodiscover_tasks()` is not called

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I am using `Django==2.0.5` and `celery==4.0.2`.
My `proj/proj/celery.py` looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj', include=[])

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
# app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I was expecting that none of the tasks decorated with `shared_task` in `tasks.py` of the apps will be discovered but to my surprise, most of the tasks can be seen under `[tasks]` when running `celery worker` with `celery worker -A proj -l INFO`.

My directory structure is somewhat like:

```
app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── factories.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
```

`CELERY_IMPORTS` is not set in `settings.py` and I have even tried with `CELERY_IMPORTS=()` and `CELERY_IMPORTS=['path/to/one/of/the/modules']`, even then all the tasks get discovered.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `Celery` caches stuff sometimes, you should try reloading the daemon used, or celery itself

Comment: I tried this on three different servers, reloading several times.

Answer (score 0):

You should try @app.task without the (bind=True) flag.
Also celery can detect all the tasks inside a module if they are in the **init** file of the module. In the django settings.py

```
CELERY_IMPORTS=("path/to/module",)
```

will cause to discover everything in that module. Make sure you haven't done something similar.

Can you also share the project folder structure?

Comment: I had the same problem using the same versions of celery and django you are using right now, recreate the project somewhere else in the exact same way and try to detect the tasks.

Comment: `(bind=False)` doesn't have any effect, I have updated the questions with the information that you requested.

Comment: I have tried this in three different envs, with the same source code, but the result is still the same.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue in one of my projects, and some tasks are being detected despite not being mentioned in CELERY_IMPORTS or in the celeryconfig file. Please share if you found a solution for that. Otherwise an issue should be opened on Github.

Comment: Additionally if you delete or comment out the tasks then they won't appear but they will still be cached somewhere in celery I guess because as soon as you comment them in they reappear. Maybe this is some default behaviour but it doesn't make a lot of sense to be that way.