# Celery discovers all previous tasks despite disabling app.autodiscover_tasks() and CELERY_IMPORTS

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

Celery discovers  all previous tasks despite disabling app.autodiscover_tasks() and CELERY_IMPORTS.

```
I am using:
django==2.0
celery==4.1.0
amqp==2.2.2
```

I had been importing a module from CELERY_IMPORTS for a long time and it was working fine, when I removed it from CELERY_IMPORTS it keeps finding it which is a very weird behaviour. 
I understand that that may be cached somewhere since it had been working for months but isn't there some command to refresh the cache. If there is which cache should I refresh combu, celery, rabbitmq?

This question was asked in 
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797585/celery-discovers-all-tasks-even-when-app-autodiscover-tasks-is-not-called/50798077?noredirect=1#comment88603562_50798077)

but no solution was found so this seems like an issue in the core functionality in celery and a solution needs to be found.

Comment: Have you restarted celery?

Comment: Yes many times, I also restarted rabbitmq

Comment: `rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages_ready messages_unacknowledged` then `rabbitmqctl purge_queue yourqueue`

Comment: Does that delete user data and other configurations?
My rabbitmq is installed in a docker container, so I tried destroying the container and rebuilding it from the scratch and obtained the same results. My guess is that this is being cached somewhere in kombu or celery.
Nonetheless I will give it a try.